# Round columns in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes and I am trying to round individual columns within each dataframe in a loop but don't seem to be getting the correct results.

```
taps = list(range(1,13))
cols_r2 = ['A','B,'C']
cols_r0 = ['D','E']

for tap in taps:
    df_dic[str(tap)+'_A'][cols_r2] = df_dic[str(tap)+'_A'][cols_r2].round(2)
    df_dic[str(tap)+'_A'][cols_r0] = df_dic[str(tap)+'_A'][cols_r0].round(0)
```

But that doesn't seem to be rounding my columns.. I still end up with several decimal places.

```
> A  B  C   D   E   
> 941.2699999999992 120.08400000000002  35567.25999999999   945.1239999999998   4121.304000000003
```

Comment: Can you show what the df_dic looks like? and did you try printing out df_dic[str(tap)+'_A'] to ensure its retrieving the right dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies I had an issue with the values being objects and not float.  That fixed it once I use `.apply(pd.to_numeric)`